# Reference of first query outcome to checkin another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query

```
SELECT abm_took_id FROM pos_took WHERE DELETEDDATE IS NOT NULL
```

it fetches the value of `abm_took_id` from table `pos_took`.

Now there is another table `pos_eook` which consists of column `cbm_bookid` which is a foreign key, that is the first table's (`pos_took`) primary key `abm_took_id` is a foriegn key to second table (`pos_eook`) as `cbm_bookid`.

Now I have to check that the `abm_took_id` fetch out from first query references are there in second table or not, for example `abm_took_id=44555` fetches out from first query, now it exists in second table or not, please advise the query where I can use in or exists operator.

Comment: Do you have a foreign key relationship defined between your pos_took and pos_eook tables?

Comment: @STLDeveloper yes ABM_TOOK_ID is the primarykey in pos_took is the foriegn ey in second table name pos_eook as cbm_bookid

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find all references in the first table (query) that are not in the second:

```
SELECT abm_took_id
FROM pos_took
WHERE DELETEDDATE IS NOT NULL and
      abm_took_id not in (select cbm_bookid
                          from pos_eook
                          where cbm_bookid is not null
                         );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , so the result or references that i am getting is the records that are present in the first table but are not in second table  , yeah I want this only thanks a lot